# How is it possible to show that the norm on the elements of Hamilton Quaternions is such that $N(\alpha \beta) = N(\alpha)N(\beta)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, normed-spaces, quaternions

Let $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{H}$ and the norm on $\mathbb{H}$ is defined as $N(\alpha) = \alpha \bar{\alpha}$.

How is it possible to show that the norm on the elements of Hamilton Quaternions is such that $N(\alpha \beta) = N(\alpha)N(\beta)$?

I know that $\bar{\alpha} \bar{\beta} = \bar{\alpha \beta}$, but I don't know how to use it?

Comment: @CameronBuie Yes, exactly! The problem is $\mathbb{H}$ is a non-commutative ring; otherwise, it sould be trivial.  Are you able to show how to solve this problem?

Comment: Note that $\overline{\alpha\beta} = \overline{\beta}\overline{\alpha}$, instead of $\overline{\alpha}\overline{\beta}$.  This might be relevant in putting together a proof.  As an example, consider $\alpha = i, \beta = j$.

Comment: The action of $\mathbb{H}$ on itself by left-multiplication gives a representation $\rho:\mathbb{H} \to \operatorname{End}(\mathbb{R}^4)$. Show that $N(\alpha) = \det \rho(\alpha)^4$.

Comment: What you want to show is essentially the [Euler's 4 square identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_four-square_identity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, rather, we have the identity $$\overline{\alpha\beta}=\bar\beta\bar\alpha$$ for any $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb H.$ Hence, $$N(\alpha\beta)=\alpha\beta\bar\beta\bar\alpha=\alpha N(\beta)\bar\alpha.$$

All that remains is to justify that $N(\beta)$ commutes multiplicatively with every element of $\Bbb H,$ regardless of our choice of $\beta\in\Bbb H.$